# Jenkins on Ubuntu gives Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - cucumber.json

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, cucumber, capybara, permission-denied

I have installed Jenkins 2.7.2 Ubuntu 16.04 and want to run cucumber files with `--out` option to save the result as `.json` file as the following command:

```
cucumber --format json_pretty --out cucumber.json features/M001_top_header.feature
```

This command works fine when run it on sheel but it gives permission error on jenkins for creating file:

> Started by user Mesut Güneş
>   Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/cuke
>   Xvfb starting$ /usr/bin//Xvfb :1 -fbdir /var/lib/jenkins/xvfb-62-1526417590499413728.fbdir
>   [cuke] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson3132297737724857573.sh
>   + cd /home/mesut/project/web-automation
>   + cucumber --format json_pretty --out cucumber.json features/M001_top_header.feature
>   DEPRECATED: #save_and_open_page_path is deprecated, please use #save_path instead. 
>   Note: Behavior is slightly different with relative paths - see documentation
>   DEPRECATED: #save_and_open_page_path is deprecated, please use #save_path instead. 
>   Note: Behavior is slightly different with relative paths - see documentation
>   Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - cucumber.json
>   Error creating formatter: json_pretty (Errno::EACCES)
>   Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
>   Xvfb stopping
>   [CucumberReportPublisher] Compiling Cucumber Reports ...
>   [CucumberReportPublisher] Copying all json files from: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/cuke to reports directory: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/cuke/builds/62
>   [CucumberReportPublisher] Found 1 json files.
>   Finished: FAILURE

When I run it with sudo, it give the following:

> sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

How can give permission to save result of cucumber run?

Comment: What directories do you have write permission to? Specify one of those for the output file

Comment: @TomWalpole I attached the whole log.